# How to add a layer on top of a video and save it iOS

Tags: ios, swift, replace, avplayer, avplayerlayer

I have a video and i want to add a layer on top of it and save it . I don't know if this works but so far i stuck on here .

```
       self.avPlayerLayer.addSublayer(self.imageView.layer)
```

then how can i save the video and replace the previous video ?

this is the drawing code

```
  override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    if self.drawing.selected == true {
        //NSLog(@"touchmoved");
        print("draw")
        let touch: UITouch = touches.first!
        let currentPoint: CGPoint = touch.locationInView(self.view)
        print("self.ImageView.image = \(self.imageView.frame)")

        // First We Set We need to begin the uigraphicsbeginimage so that we can draw the image
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(self.imageView.frame.width, self.imageView.frame.height))

        //Drawing board frame
        self.imageView.image?.drawInRect(self.imageView.frame)

        //Drawing Atiitrbutes
        CGContextSetLineCap(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), .Round)
        CGContextSetLineWidth(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), brush)
        CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), self.drawColor.CGColor)
        CGContextSetBlendMode(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), .Normal)
        CGContextBeginPath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
        CGContextMoveToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), self.lastPoint.x, self.lastPoint.y)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), currentPoint.x, currentPoint.y)
        CGContextStrokePath(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext())
        print("UIGRAPHICS  = \(UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext())")

        //Set image to image
        self.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        self.lastPoint = currentPoint
        self.view.setNeedsDisplay()

    }
}
```

Comment: Show some code of your app...

Comment: You mean "save" the layer into the video?

Comment: i have a video that i recorded and i have implement a drawing color like snapchat does on top of the video but how can i save the video with the layer on top of it which is the drawing /

Comment: You can refer to this link : https://www.raywenderlich.com/30200/avfoundation-tutorial-adding-overlays-and-animations-to-videos
Its in Objective C though, will update you if I  get anything in swift

Comment: Thanks a lot , it helps me :)