# Add layer on AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer and save in the live video

Tags: swift, camera, avfoundation, video-recording

I found similar threads like this two: [Save what user see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39915474/save-what-user-see-in-avcapturevideopreviewlayer), [Add layer on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37274766/how-to-add-a-layer-on-top-of-a-video-and-save-it-ios) But they didn't help.

The following section shows a `PreviewLayer` of the `captureSession`. Then I put a blue `CGLayer` on top of it. Everything is displayed correctly.

```
func showCameraOutput(in videoView: UIView) {
    previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.captureSession)
    previewLayer?.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
    previewLayer?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: videoView.frame.width, height: videoView.frame.height)
    previewLayer?.connection?.videoOrientation = .landscapeRight
            
    let blueLayer = CALayer()
    blueLayer.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue.withAlphaComponent(0.5).cgColor
    blueLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: videoView.frame.width/2, height: videoView.frame.height)
    previewLayer?.addSublayer(blueLayer)
   
    videoView.layer.sublayers?.removeAll(where: { $0 is AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer })
    
    if let previewLayer = previewLayer {
        videoView.layer.insertSublayer(previewLayer, at: 0)
    }
}
```

When I save the video, the blue layer is no longer there.

```
func fileOutput(_ output: AVCaptureFileOutput, didFinishRecordingTo outputFileURL: URL, from connections: [AVCaptureConnection], error: Error?) {
    UISaveVideoAtPathToSavedPhotosAlbum(outputFileURL.path, nil, nil, nil)
    
}
```

Is it not possible to save layers to a live video? Or is something else saved? How can I access this resource then?

I do not want to *not* edit the video afterwards. The goal is to put a layer on top of a live video and save it with it. Maybe I just need a hint for google.

Answer (score 1):

In your setup, the video frames take two different routes through your app:

1. Camera (`AVCaptureDeviceInput`) → `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer` → Core Animation (`CALayer` composition and blending) → Screen
2. Camera (`AVCaptureDeviceInput`) → `AVCaptureFileOutput` (writing video frames to a file)

So path 2 doesn't know anything about what's happening on the Core Animation layer. It just writes the unmodified camera frames to a file.

In order to have a composition/blending phase that is visible in preview and output, you need a much more elaborate setup, I'm afraid. It would look something like this:

`AVCaptureDeviceInput` → `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput` → `AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` → `CVPixelBuffer` → Composition/Blending (probably with Core Image) → new, edited `CVPixelBuffer`

The new `CVPixelBuffer` will then go to two targets:

1. display with `MTKView`
2. `AVAssetWriterInputPixelBufferAdaptor` → `AVAssetWriterInput` → `AVAssetWriter` → video file

I hope this helps with googling.